Python Discord bot commands not working no errors in console
I've been trying to code a bot for my discord group to get alerts when I buy and sell stock, and I just cant seem to figure out why the code works and runs with no errors in console but the bot doesnt respond to any "!alert" commands.
I have enabled all the necessary options in the discord development portal and same goes for permissions within the discord server.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()  # Create a new Intents object with default settings
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)  # Pass the Intents object to the Bot

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')

@bot.command()
async def alert(ctx, action, stock, strike_price, option_type, expiration_date, premium):
    # Ensure the command issuer has the correct role
    if "tophalerts" in [role.name for role in ctx.author.roles]:
        # Create the embed message
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Stock Option Alert", color=0x00ff00)
        embed.add_field(name="Action", value=action, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Stock", value=stock, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Strike Price", value=strike_price, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Option Type", value=option_type, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Expiration Date", value=expiration_date, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Premium", value=premium, inline=False)

        # Send the embed message in the 'alerts' channel
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                if channel.name == 'toph-alerts':
                    await channel.send(embed=embed)

        # Send a DM with the embed message to all members with the 'alerts' role
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                if "tophalerts" in [role.name for role in member.roles]:
                    await member.send(embed=embed)

bot.run('bot-token')


discord may catch all errors and hide them - to work stable all time - so you may need to change settings in logging to see errors. See discord doc: Setting Up Logging

I have set up the code with logging here but still no errors in the console.

you can still use logger or normal file to save information which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. Maybe it helps to see where is the problem. Maybe some values are wrong and some for-loop works on empty data or if always gives false - and it can't send messages. You could use file (or at least print() to check what you have in channel.name and in [role.name for role in member.roles]. And check [role.name for role in ctx.author.roles] - maybe  ctx.author has no role tophalerts

You need to activate the message_content intent. Without it, your bot is unable to process any message command. Also, for the DM part of your command, you will also need the members intent to iterate through the members of your bot's guilds.
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

On a side note, you don't need to loop twice in your bot's guilds, you can do it only once and check both channels and members role :
for guild in bot.guilds:
    # Send the embed message in the 'alerts' channel
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
         if channel.name == 'toph-alerts':
             await channel.send(embed=embed)
    # Send a DM with the embed message to all members with the 'alerts' role
     for member in guild.members:
          if "tophalerts" in [role.name for role in member.roles]:
               await member.send(embed=embed)

